# Are there buttons like these built into the Android that Devs can use?

Tags: android, button, tabs, navigation, built-in

I want to try to get nice buttons that will work similar to tabs down the bottom of my app, but I am wondering if there are buttons like this built in:

[image]

It would make navigation better, and developing a lot easier & faster if they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example screenshot is showing a mostly-untouched stock Android 2.2 launcher. Since it's open source you can take a look at how it's done. [Here's the layout file it uses.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=blob;f=res/layout-port/launcher.xml;h=8dc50927929e6fdf9756f6d4be4c364f466bf25e;hb=HEAD)

Note the RelativeLayout at the bottom containing the three "hotseat" buttons. Each of them uses a custom style to get the appearance, those styles are defined [here.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=blob;f=res/values/styles.xml;h=c2082111cc8b1aa1c955f049a70ee3a3e30680cd;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing in the picture is HTC Sense Launcher. It's an add-on and not part of core Android OS.

BTW it's easy to do custom transparent button like this. Let me know if you need any help with this.

**Update:**

Use this example to create a custom Dialog, that is not modal and is floating and transparent.

```
dialog = new Dialog(activityRequestingProgressDialog);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_upload);
progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressText);
progressText.setText("0 %");
progressText.setTextSize(18);
Button buttonCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cancelProgressDialog();
        }
});
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
dialog.show();
```

And the dialog layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/progressDialog"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:text="@string/progress_title"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressDialog"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                 android:layout_width="150dp"
                 android:layout_height="34dp"
                 android:paddingRight="10dp"
                 android:max="100"
                 android:progress="0"
                 android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:id="@+id/progressText"
              android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:text="@string/button_options_text"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_grey"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_options"
            android:drawablePadding="-5dip"
            android:background="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is an example of a progress dialog with progress bar, text and cancel button. You can easily change this to three buttons. Note that button is transparent with icon and text.

Comment: It's not Sense launcher, it's on roms that don't have sense

Comment: Oh yeah, I know they are the launcher buttons, but I was just wondering if there is something similar to how these work in the SDK. It's about the style of the buttons and how they work. At the moment in my app, I have tabs down the bottom, but they look horrible and are separated into tabs. What I am looking for is something like the Launcher that would operate like tabs. The tabs never go away, they are always on screen and intents change without having to refresh the screen. I am looking for this sort of navigation. Is there anything built-in that would allow that?

Comment: Try custom Dialog that is not modal. It floats above, but does not block an Activity. I have no experience what would happen if Activity would be replaced with different Activity within same app. I edited the post to show an example.

Comment: @adamp - what do you propose?

Comment: Using a standard layout will work just fine. Dialogs are not necessary to layer elements over one another. `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, others in the Android framework, or even custom-written layouts can position views this way.

Comment: IMHO the advantage of Dialog is that you can simply show it over any Activity without the need to change the activity's layout.

Comment: That approach will also make your app very difficult to navigate with a keyboard, trackball, or d-pad in addition to other added complexity. :)